# Newman run 1 folder and rest of the collection

Tags: api, postman, newman

I have Test.Collection in Postman, where I have 2 folders and some requests on the collection level (they are not in the folders).

I run this collection with Newman in CLI like this:

```
newman run *path_to_collection* -f *folder_name_in_the_collection*
```

This command runs only the folder in the collection but not the requests on the collection level.

Is there a way to run 1 folder and rest of the requests in collection?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this if the Requests at the top level of the Collection have unique names:

```
newman run collection.json --folder "Request_1" --folder "Request_2" --folder "Folder_1"
```